Rails test segfaults on mac
I'm working on tests with rails on my macbook (m2 chip).
When I start bin/rails test I obtain a crash (I have to ctrl + C to exit) with an output that starts like this :
/Users/tristan/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon/easy/operations.rb:30: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000110
ruby 3.1.1p18 (2022-02-18 revision 53f5fc4236) [arm64-darwin22]
-- Crash Report log information ----------------------
See Crash Report log file in one of the following locations:
 * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
 * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
for more details.
Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file in bug reports.
-- Control frame information ------------------------------------
c:0124 p:---- s:0792 e:000791 CFUNC  :easy_perform
c:0123 p:0014 s:0787 e:000786 METHOD
/Users/tristan/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon/easy/operations.rb:30
c:0122 p:0020 s:0783 e:000782 METHOD /Users/tristan/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus/request/operations.rb:16
c:0121 p:0025 s:0778 e:000777 METHOD /Users/tristan/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus/request/cacheable.rb:18
c:0120 p:0033 s:0773 e:000772 METHOD /Users/tristan/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus/request/block_connection.rb:31
c:0119 p:0040 s:0769 e:000768 METHOD /Users/tristan/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus/request/stubbable.rb:25
c:0118 p:0019 s:0764 e:000763 METHOD /Users/tristan/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus/request/before.rb:26
c:0117 p:0025 s:0760 e:000759 METHOD /Users/tristan/.rbenv/versions/3.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.1/lib/typhoeus/request/actions.rb:38
c:0116 p:0085 s:0754 e:000753 METHOD /Users/tristan/workspace/lakaa/monorepo/backend/app/services/pdf_service.rb:24
c:0115 p:0660 s:0744 e:000743 METHOD /Users/tristan/workspace/lakaa/monorepo/backend/app/actions/reports/build_digest.rb:100

Here is a list of things I tried :

Running with sudo => I get a crash as well but with only the following as an output :
objc[77684]: +[NSNumber initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.



It looks like the crash comes from Ethon, I found a fix on github that I tried. But then instead it comes from pg.

When I'm running a small bunch of tests (for exemple by running only one test file) I don't get any error. So I assume it could be a memory leak  ?


Also, tests are running correctly under github CI and docker.

I am bit unclear. The way I read this post is you have solved the issue you are posting about and are now receiving a seg fault from the pg gem? If that is the case you should update the question to show the current error. In doing so please copy the stack trace rather than posting an image of it.

I replaced the image of the error output by the trace.
I think that the error is not caused by Ethon. As I said, if I run small amount of tests, I don't get any error. Also I updated my question with new information.

Does this fail on the latest Ruby, like 3.3.0 or even 3.2.x? This is likely a bug in the C extension in that gem.
